Understanding (0 + Days | Subject) in lme4
The vignette "Translating lme4 models to sommer" of the sommer package explains
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 + Days | Subject), data=DT)

as

"This is the a model where you assume that the random effect has different intercepts based on the levels of another variable but there’s not a main effect. The 0 in the intercept in lme4 assumes that random slopes interact with an intercept but without a main effect."

As I understand, the above model specification suggests a random slope effect of Days nested in Subject, but the random intercept variance is forced to 0, meaning that all Subjects have identical intercept. I do not quite understand why the sommer vignette states "the random effect has different intercepts".
Please let me know if my understanding is somewhere problematic.

Your interpretation is correct, with that code random intercept variance is forced to zero (but random slopes are estimated). I think maybe in early versions of lme4 that code did estimate random intercept too (but specified random intercept and slope as uncorrelated), maybe that's the source of the sommer package text? But I'm not sure about that.
